# pandas read csv then remove leading 0 then rewrtie CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Hey Guys I have a csv named `info.csv`

> Number,Name
>  01,john
>  02,mike
>  010,kevin
>  012,joe
>   020,rob

I want to read in the csv using python pandas from my path remove the leading 0 and then rewrite it to a new csv named newinfo.csv. I have not been able to find any type of answer on SOF with this process.

Comment: Please provide examples of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I import with Pandas it recognizes the first column as an integer and removes the leading zeros.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("info.csv")
df.to_csv("newinfo.csv", index=False)
```

Or you could change the type to integer yourself.

```
df.Number = df.Number.astype(int)
```

Comment: What if the columns were opposite?

Comment: Column order shouldn't matter. If it doesn't import as integer for some reason you can change the data type manually. Added to answer above.

Comment: If you used this answer to solve your problem could you mark it as answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any code you can show for this? What have you tried so far?

You can do something like:

```
with open('your_file.csv', 'rb') as f:
  data = f.read()
```

And then slice the first element to remove the 0

Cheers!